# Apache deadlock when writing in file

Tags: apache-2.4, http, httpd

Apache v2.4.56 on Solaris, with libapr 1.6.2. When starting, it spawns 5 httpd processes.

Occasionally the server hangs and does not accept requests. It's even impossible to connect to port 80.

I did a core dump of each of the 5 processes and found out that two of them seems to be stuck in the same function write(). I suppose they are writing events in the log file but I'm not sure. Here is how I configured the log:

```
ErrorLog /data/log/HTTP.apache.log
LogLevel info
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %f %t \t%I \t%O \t%D" common
    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -tHTTP -pdaemon.info" common
</IfModule>
```

Here is an example of the callstack of the first process that seems dead locked:

```
------------  lwp# 6 / thread# 6  ---------------
 ffffffff730cb048 write    (b, ffffffff7e75b9ff, 1)
 ffffffff57d28ca8 apr_file_write (0x100267338?, 0xffffffff7e75b9ff?, 0xffffffff7e75b9e0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?) + 1c8
 ffffffff57d28ff4 apr_file_putc (0x1?, 0x100267338?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x1?, 0x0?) + 1c
 ffffffff57d392c8 apr_pollset_wakeup (0x100266a50?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x100266a18?, 0x0?) + 20
 00000001000b4888 TO_QUEUE_APPEND (0x100221228?, 0x10032b700?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x100221258?, 0x10032b7b0?) + f0
 00000001000b6f5c process_socket (0x1002675c0?, 0x10032b378?, 0x10032b400?, 0x0?, 0x1?, 0x3?) + 8bc
 00000001000ba14c worker_thread (0x1002675c0?, 0x100215af0?, 0xffffffff7f582240?, 0xfffc00?, 0x1?, 0x3?) + 494
 ffffffff57d407a0 dummy_worker (0x1002675c0?, 0x0?, 0x1?, 0xffffffff57d40788?, 0x0?, 0x0?) + 18
 ffffffff730c58b4 _lwp_start (0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
```

The stack of the second process is exactly the same.

What surprises me is that in libapr's  source code for apr_file_write(), there is no locking mechanism when calling the write() function.

Do you have any idea what could cause the deadlock? Is the problem the config that use CustomLog with a pipe?